# docker-compose how to create multiple containers with using the same image

Tags: docker

for some reason, I need to create the container with the same image, But when I started the second one, It just restarted the fist one's container

the first yml file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

  php:
    image:php:php73-fpm
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9501:9501"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/../:/var/www/html/
    networks:
      - app_net
    container_name: php
networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
```

the second yml file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

  php:
    image:php:php73-fpm
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "19000:19000"
      - "19501:19501"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/../:/var/www/html/
    networks:
      - app_net2
    container_name: php73
networks:
  app_net2:
    driver: bridge
```

when I run `docker-compose up -d` to start the first one:

```
$ cd ~/Document/php/work/docker/
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "docker_app_net" with driver "bridge"
Creating php ... done
```

then I switch the directory to the second yml file

```
$ cd ../../private/docker/
$ docker-compose up -d
Recreating php ... done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compose has a notion of a [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name).  By default the project name is the basename of the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file.  In your example both directories are named `docker` (even if they're in different parent directories) so Compose looks for a project named `docker` and a container named `php`, and finds a match.

There are four ways to override this:

1. Rename one of the directories.
2. Set the [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name).
3. Create a [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) in the current directory, and set `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` there.
4. Use the [`docker-compose -p` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/) (on *every* `docker-compose` command).

Within your `docker-compose.yml` file, the second part of `ports:` needs to match what the container is listening on; this is allowed to be different from the first part.  So use the same 9500/9501 in both files.

Another consequence of the Compose project naming is that the standard names of containers, volumes, and networks that Compose creates will be prefixed with the project name.  If the project name (current directory name) is `docker2`, and you reduce the Compose file to

```yaml
version: "3.1"
services:
  php:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "19000:9000"
      - "19501:9501"
    # no manual container_name: or networks:
```

The container will be named `docker2_php_1`, and it will be attached to a network named `docker2_default`; these will be different from the container/network created in the `docker1` project/directory.

Comment: excellent!, Your answer perfectly told me why and how, I tried your suggest and It work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two containers with the same name. Since both names are just `php`, Docker thought they were settings that were supposed to be merged for the same container. Rename one of them.

Comment: great, It works, But I still have a question, actually, I have others docker-compose.yml, For simple, I named them A.yml and B.yml. Both of them started three container, and one of them was the same image: `redis:5.0.5`, Service's name is the same:`redis`. but when I started B.yml, It did nothing like : `creating xxx done...   creating xxx done...  restarting  redis-A done...`   (redis-A is container name in A.yml, B.yml's container name is redis-B)

Comment: @afraid.jpg Having two services with the same name will also end badly. Don't do that either.